# Alternative to using Session Variables for Authentication

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm still new to PHP, but a lot of the things ive read suggest using Session Variables to check whether or not the user is logged in. IE I would add an includes.php file that would checked if `$_SESSION['login'] == true` but seeing as how Session variables are just cookies, someone could easily set that themselves right? What is another way to go about checked to see if a user has been authenticated?

Comment: Read the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221447/what-do-i-need-to-store-in-the-php-session-when-user-logged-in/1225668#1225668

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are a lot different than cookies. All the data is stored on the server in  a session file, the cookie itself only stores the browser identifier to match against the right session file on the server. One way or the other you will need cookies, so I believe its pretty safe to say that you would be safe using sessions for checking authenticated users.

Comment: LOL, same opening sentence, 12sec earlier than me.

Comment: @Michael haha yeah, i just edited and changed to make it less confusing :)

Answer (score 1):

Session variables are not just cookies.  The client browser recieves a cookie which attaches it to a session on the server, but only the server can set and read variables from `$_SESSION`.

While a client could pass any information they wanted to the server with a cookie, the session ID is difficult (though not impossible) to guess, making it difficult to hijack another user's session.

A common way to protect against hijacking a session is to store in `$_SESSION` a fingerprint of the user's IP address, user-agent string, or some other identifiable string. This could also be a random token string you generate and send down to the client while also storing in `$_SESSION`.  On the next form post, you expect the token to be sent in a hidden input and match it against the one you've stored on the server.

Answer (score 1):

> but seeing as how Session variables
>   are just cookies, someone could easily
>   set that themselves right?

Wrong! A session cookie will contain just the [token of the session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID), the session itself and its values will reside on the server. The token value, which the cookie will have, would be used to locate the session.

> What is another way to go about
>   checked to see if a user has been
>   authenticated?

Store authentication in a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you authenticate over HTTPS the cookie will be secured.   Also, when you set a session you're handling the client a cookie with a random session UUID that will translate to a key value store on your server, a client can't just set "login=true" and get access.

Comment: HTTPS only secures the data send via a login-form(or any other form). It does not secure the way a user provides his session identifier.