# session_regenerate_id in Django. Does it exist?

Tags: python, django

I wonder if there exists a function in `Django` similar to that in `PHP`, which is `session_regenerate_id()`. I want to use that kind of function to rotate `sessionid` on each N requests in order to provide more security. In `PHP` I would use in the manner described by this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26210/andrew-moore) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221447/what-do-i-need-to-store-in-the-php-session-when-user-logged-in). I just want to implement the same thing in my `Django` project, but I'm new to `Django` and do not know if there exists such a function that could change user's session id on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such function exists in django - [`request.session.cycle_key()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.cycle_key).